# Exact only one date for id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I have a table with many records related to one id and I need to select only the one records with the most recent StartDate for each id. How can I do it simply?
For example, for id 5001145 I need to select only the row with start date 2020-03-20.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.startdate = (select max(t2.startdate)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.id = t.id
                    );
```

Another variation is `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by startdate desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, is there a possibility not to display the rownumber (sequm) in the select?

Comment: @sear1234 . . . You can select the columns that you do want or use the first method (which might be a tad faster if you have an index on `(id, startdate)`.